# Add trendline to SSRS Line Chart

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, trendline

Is there anyway to create a moving average on a SSRS 2008 R2 Line Chart? I see that there is an option but I can not get it to work properly.

#### Calculated Series Formula Screenshot

[image: Calculated Series Formula Screenshot]

The table that I am pulling this data from is an roll up table that has aggregates based on different categories and issues. Here is a sample shot of the table:

`Status      IssueCount  Date

Not Started     19      2014-02-04 00:00:00.000 
Requirements    1       2014-02-04 00:00:00.000 
Not Started     2       2014-02-04 00:00:00.000 
Approved        1       2014-06-10 00:00:00.000`

This is the graph that I am trying to accomplish in SSRS: [Status by Counts with Moving Averages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToOaM.png)

If I remove the Calculated Series; everything executes as it should in the line graph, but as soon as the calulated average is added I receive the error: Formula Data Object - Input Series doesn't exist in the Series Collection: Count

Comment: Can you share the calculation associated with the series?

Comment: It looks like you have a pipe character `|` at the start of your Series Group name: `|Status` - I wonder if that is the issue.

Comment: There is no pipe line in the actual data, i was just trying to decrypt the fieldname.
The Calculated series is just me selecting "moving average" in the formula drop down. I added the photo to the original issue

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found anything in the MS docs on this yet to add information to this answer, but it appears that using calculated series with chart series is extremely limited or unsupported. The quote I found was:

"*The calculated series can't be used if the chart series have more than 2 units in the current reporting services.*"

[Link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/130acf60-c7ab-4497-8afa-97d3245cd716/formula-data-object-input-series-doesnt-exist-in-series-collection?forum=sqlreportingservices)

If anyone can expand on this very limited explaination it would be greatly appreciated.